# Imputing/Interpolating Income data for missing years

Tags: time-series, data-imputation

I am building a dataset so I can do time-series analysis at the census-tract level in the United States. I have income data for 1990, 2000, 2006-2010. Is there a way to impute/estimate income values for the years 2001-2005 at the census tract level based off the existing income data I have? If the answer is yes, what would be the stata commands I would want to use?